# PulpSolverError: Not Available check permissions

Tags: python, conda, pulp, coin-or-cbc

I run the 'PuLP' solver on my OSx and after some conda updates it stopped recognizing the solver.

I call:

```
solver = pulp.get_solver('PULP_CBC_CMD')
prob.solve(solver)
```

I get:

```
pulp.apis.core.PulpSolverError: PULP_CBC_CMD: Not Available (check permissions on /opt/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pulp/apis/../solverdir/cbc/osx/64/cbc)
```

When I asked for a path I got:

```
pl.pulp_cbc_path
Out[9]: '/opt/anaconda3/envs/ExMAS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pulp/apis/../solverdir/cbc/osx/64/cbc
```

Maybe interestingly, my conda env is for python 3.9 and my PuLP is in3.8 folder

My PuLP is 2.6.0

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, seems fixed.

when I unistalled `pulp`- both from `conda` and `pip` (I think by default my `conda` `pulp` was used) and then installed them again (only with `pip` now)

it seems to be solved. maybe this was issue with `conda` installation and pip installation was fine...?

Answer (score 1):

I installed `pulp` with `conda install -c conda-forge pulp` on macOS, had the same error

```
pulp.apis.core.PulpSolverError: PULP_CBC_CMD: Not Available (check permissions on...
```

I could not uninstall `pulp`

```
conda remove pulp
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - python=3.1
```

So I just created a new env and installed `pulp` with `pip`

```
conda create --name myNewEnv --clone base
conda activate myNewEnv
conda install pandas
pip install pulp
```

It ran in this case. There are some [threads](https://github.com/coin-or/pulp/discussions/384) about `pulp` installed not with `pip` having problems with permissions, etc...